# Google Chrome - change from metro mode to desktop mode

Tags: google-chrome, desktop, modern-ui

On one of our desktop computers Google Chrome suddenly opens in metro mode. The user does not remember to having changed that setting.

How can I force Google Chrome to open in desktop mode again ?

This is on a Windows 8.1 computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desktop mode can be restored by changing the "Relaunch Chrome on the Desktop". Go to the menu (three horizontal lines) and select "Relaunch Chrome on the Desktop"

Hope this helps.